# fancybox not working for div but working without it

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using the fancybox like

```
setPopupText("Attention", "Setting the message as handled, please wait");
```

where setPopupText function is as follows:

```
function setPopupText(title, bodyMessage) {
$.fancybox(bodyMessage, {
    minWidth: 'auto',
    minHeight: 'auto',
    fitToView: false,
    width: '20%',
    height: '16%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    cyclic: true,
    transitionIn: 'elastic',
    transitionOut: 'elastic',
    titlePosition: 'outside'
});
}
```

It works ok, but then I want to create a div with html and show it when I want like this

```
<a href="#divPopUp" id="btnPopup">Load Form</a>
<div id="divPopUp" @*style="display:none"*@>
    <h2>Attention</h2>
    <p>
        <a id="skypeCall" href="#">
            <img style="width:32px;height:32px;" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Map/call.jpg")" alt="Call"/>
            &nbsp;Call </a>&nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:$.fancybox.close();">Close</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
</div>
```

and calling it like

```
$("#btnPopup").fancybox({
            minWidth: 'auto',
            minHeight: 'auto',
            fitToView: false,
            width: '50%',
            height: '40%',
            autoSize: false,
            closeClick: false,
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            cyclic: true,
            transitionIn: 'elastic',
            transitionOut: 'elastic',
            titlePosition: 'outside'
        });
```

But the popup doesn't appear, what can be wrong?
I'm using aspnet mvc 4, but as the first one works I don't think it's related to it.
Also I'm using fancybox2
Thanks!! Guillermo.

Comment: try adding the attribute name="divPopUp" to the div #divPopUp or add the content parameter to the fancybox settings object like content: div.html()

Comment: maybe you just need to wrap `$("#btnPopup").fancybox()` inside the `.ready()` method

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the cause. I have a google map div and the div of the popup was after the google maps div, I moved it before and it started to appear.
Thanks @jfk and @Alex